# Unique, minimal norm solution of a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Suppose an equation $Ax=b$ has non-unique solutions. Prove that there exist a unique vector $x_{min}$ satisfying $Ax_{min}=b$ whose norm is the smallest among the solutions of that equation.

The solution of a non-homogeneous linear system consists of the particular $x_p$ and homogeneous solutions $x_h \in \textrm{null }A$, thus $x=x_p+x_h$. Then
$$
|x|^2 = |x_p+x_h|^2 = |x_p|^2+|x_h|^2 + (x_p,x_h) + (x_h,x_p)
$$
But I don't know how to reach the minimum of the right hand side.

EDIT: It turns out that I can find $x_p$ such that it lies in $(\textrm{null }A)^\perp$, so that in this case $|x|^2 = |x_p|^2+|x_h|^2$. Therefore by choosing $x_h=0$, it becomes $|x|^2 = |x_p|^2$. But how can I prove that this is unique and yields the smallest norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homogenous solutions constitute a subspace. Choose $x_p$ to be in its orthogonal complement (this is always possible). Then the cross terms on the right side of your equation vanish.

Comment: Your answer suggests that a particular solution can generally be non-unique? Is that true?

Comment: @nougako: A "particular solution" is any vector of your choice that solves $Ax=b$. You're _supposing_ in the first sentence of your question that it is not unique.

Comment: I thought when an equation is said to have multiple solutions, it means that it's $x_h$ which can assume any vector so long as it is in $\textrm{null }A$ but that $x_p$ is always unique for a given equation. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: @nougako: Yes, your understanding is wrong. $x_p$ is just _some_ solution that you can pick in whichever way you please -- the $x_h$s then tell you how to find all the _other_ particular solutions once you have decided on _one_ of them to be your $x_p$.

Comment: Suppose $u_{h1}$ and $u_{h2}$ are basis in $\textrm{null }A$ (so null A is 2-dimensional space), then a vector of the form ,e.g. $x = x_p' + 3u_{h1}+4u_{h2}$ and $x = x_p'' + 2u_{h1}+3u_{h2}$, where $x_p'' = x_p'+u_{h1}+u_{h2}$, is also a solution with differing particular parts. Does it illustrate what you mean?

Comment: @nougako: I think we should go to an even more concrete example. Take the equation $x+y=5$ -- that is, $A=[1\;1]$ and $b=(5)$. Then the homogenous solutions are $$ \{(t,t)\mid t\in\mathbb R\} = \{\ldots,(-2,2),(-1,1),(0,0),(1,-1),(\pi,-\pi),\ldots\} $$ and we can choose any particular solution we like, such as $x_p=(1,4)$ or $x_p=(3,2)$. Then the solution set can be written _either_ as $$ \{ (1,4)+(t,-t)\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$$ or as $$ \{ (3,2)+(t,-t) \mid t\in \mathbb R\} $$ and _each_ of these sets is the entire solution set.

Comment: But it does not make sense to ask what is "the" particular and homogenous parts of a specific solution. In the above case $(6,-1)$ is a solution, but it does not make sense to ask whether this solution should be decomposed as $(1,4)+(5,-5)$ or $(3,2)+(3,-3)$. Or perhaps even $(6,-1)+(0,0)$.

Comment: Ah I get it now. So, I can choose the particular solution such that it lies in $(\textrm{null }A)^\perp$. Thanks!

Comment: @nougako: Yes, exactly.

Comment: I figured out that the uniqueness and the "norm-smallestness" of the solution $x_p \in (\textrm{null }A)^\perp$ have not been completely addressed. Would you please take a look again at the added part in my question?

Comment: @nougako: Suppose $x_1$ and $x_2$ are particular solutions that are both in the orthogonal component of the null space. Then $\Delta x= x_1-x_2$ is in the null space, and we have $$ |x_1|^2 = |x_2|^2+|\Delta x|^2 = (|x_1|^2+|-\Delta x|^2)+|\Delta x|^2 = |x_1|^2 + 2|\Delta x|^2$$ so $|\Delta x|^2 = 0$ which is absurd unless $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: But I don't understand why you feel it hasn't been established that it gives the smallest norm. There's no way for $|x_p|^2+|x_h|^2$ to be smaller than $|x_p|^2+0$ because a square cannot be negative.

Comment: How can $\Delta x$ be in the null space when it is the difference between two vectors in the orthogonal complement of the null space? I would expect that $\Delta x$ should also be in the orthogonal complement of the null space.

Comment: @nugaco: $x_1-x_2$ is in the null space because $A(x_1-x_2)=Ax_1-Ax_2=b-b=0$. You're correct that it is _also_ in the orthogonal complement -- and the only way for that to be true at the same time is if $\Delta x=0$, or in other words $x_1=x_2$. Thus, uniqueness!

Comment: Alright. So I conclude that if we find a particular solution in the orthogonal complement of null A, then that particular solution is the only solution in that space.
The "norm-smallestness" still concerns me because I haven't proved whether the norm of the particular solution we have found in $(\textrm{null }A)^\perp$ is indeed smaller than any other solution outside $(\textrm{null }A)^\perp$.

Comment: @nougako: I _still_ don't understand why you say that the minimality of the norm has not been proved. If $x_p$ is a particular solution in the orthogonal complement, every _other_ particular solution would differ from $x_p$ by a nonzero $x_h$, and therefore the norm of that other particular solution would differ from $|x_p|$ as $$|x_p+x_h|^2 = |x_p|^2 + |x_h|^2 $$ I have said this multiple times now, and you seem to ignore it each time I say it. Do you not agree that $|x_h|^2$ is necessarily positive when $x_h\ne 0$? Do you not agree that larger norm-squared means larger norm?

Comment: I didn't ignore your previous explanation. As I understood you previously considered the case of two particular solutions in $(\textrm{null }A)^\perp$. While what I was pondering about is the case when one of the particular solutions is in null A. Fortunately, your last comment clear up everything although it took me sometime to realize that the difference between two particular solutions is a homogeneous solution. But thank you very much, I understand this matter completely now.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extensive discussion below the accepted answer, so I just add here a compact proof regarding uniqueness.

Let $x, y$ be two vectors such that $Ax=b$, $Ay=b$ and $x,y\in(\ker A)^\perp$. We then have the following two things:

- Since $x$ and $y$ are some solutions to the same linear equation, $x=y+x_0$ for some $x_0\in \ker A$
- Since $x$ and $y$ are in $(\ker A)^\perp$ so is $x-y\in(\ker A)^\perp$

Thus, we have that
$$||x-y||^2=\langle x-y, x-y\rangle=\langle x-y, x_0\rangle=0.$$